# Materialize-stepper for multi-form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Materialize-stepper from this github package - https://github.com/Kinark/Materialize-stepper. I am applying all the links required but for some reason, the layout look like it should. I am even adding the css contents in the file. For example, this is the codepen link provided by the user - https://codepen.io/Kinark/pen/VKrjJp

And below is my code which is exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mstepper.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mstepper.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
    .btn,
    .btn-large,
    .btn-small,
    .btn-flat {
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    }

    .card {
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="section grey lighten-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col xl4 l6 m10 s12 offset-xl4 offset-l3 offset-m1">
                    <h3 class="light center-align blue-text">Sign up form</h3>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">

                            <ul data-method="GET" class="stepper linear">
                                <li class="step active">
                                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">E-mail</div>
                                    <div class="step-content">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate" required>
                                                <label for="email">Your e-mail</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="step-actions">
                                            <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step"
                                                data-feedback="anyThing">Continue</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="step">
                                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Step 2</div>
                                    <div class="step-content">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate"
                                                    required>
                                                <label for="password">Your password</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="step-actions">
                                            <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step">CONTINUE</button>
                                            <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn-flat previous-step">BACK</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="step">
                                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Callback</div>
                                    <div class="step-content">
                                        End!!!!!
                                        <div class="step-actions">
                                            <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step"
                                                data-feedback="noThing">ENDLESS CALLBACK!</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function anyThing(destroyFeedback) {
            setTimeout(function () { destroyFeedback(true); }, 1500);
        }

        function noThing(destroyFeedback) {
            setTimeout(function () { destroyFeedback(true); }, 10000);
        }

        var stepperDiv = document.querySelector('.stepper');
        console.log(stepperDiv);
        var stepper = new MStepper(stepperDiv);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing main `materialize` dependencies:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js
```

```js
function anyThing(destroyFeedback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    destroyFeedback(true);
  }, 1500);
}

function noThing(destroyFeedback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    destroyFeedback(true);
  }, 10000);
}

var stepperDiv = document.querySelector('.stepper');
console.log(stepperDiv);
var stepper = new MStepper(stepperDiv);
```

```css
.btn,
.btn-large,
.btn-small,
.btn-flat {
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.card {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/materialize-stepper@3.0.0-beta.1.0.1/dist/css/mstepper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/materialize-stepper@3.0.0-beta.1.0.1/dist/js/mstepper.min.js"></script>

<div class="section grey lighten-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col xl4 l6 m10 s12 offset-xl4 offset-l3 offset-m1">
        <h3 class="light center-align blue-text">Sign up form</h3>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">

            <ul data-method="GET" class="stepper linear">
              <li class="step active">
                <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">E-mail</div>
                <div class="step-content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate" required>
                      <label for="email">Your e-mail</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="step-actions">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step" data-feedback="anyThing">Continue</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="step">
                <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Step 2</div>
                <div class="step-content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" required>
                      <label for="password">Your password</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="step-actions">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step">CONTINUE</button>
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn-flat previous-step">BACK</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="step">
                <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Callback</div>
                <div class="step-content">
                  End!!!!!
                  <div class="step-actions">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step" data-feedback="noThing">ENDLESS CALLBACK!</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```